# How to detect if a point is on the boundary( i.e 'edges') of a shape

Tags: c#, drawing, paint

I have a win forms application, in which I can draw some shapes(like rectangle/ circle) and also can fill them with color.
Now, if i selected a brush to fill a shape (say rectangle) and click on the 'boundary' of shape (i don't want to fill the shape in this case), 
How can i detect that the 'point' is on boundary ( i mean 'edges') of a shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Represent your shape as a GraphicsPath, then use the [IsOutlineVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.isoutlinevisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to determine if the point is under the outline.

The IsVisible() method will tell you if the point is within the entire GraphicsPath.

Comment: Good answer! did not know about GraphicsPath! +1

Comment: .Net is a BIG world.  I've been using it for ten years and I'm still discovering "new" functions; at least they are "new" to me!

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 coordinates of the shape position.

```
shape.X
shape.Y
```

you have also the size of the shape

```
shape.Height
shape.Width
```

You have the coordinates of the mouse position

```
mouse.X
mouse.Y
```

If mouse.X is between shape.X and shape.X+shape.Width and mouse.Y is equal to shape.Y or shape.Y+shape.Heigh and so on for a rectangle

For different but "regular" shapes you should calculate it in a similarway

For complex and irregular shape you should discompose it to smal pieces and do the same calculation:

check this: [determine if a point sits inside an arbitrary shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486499/determine-if-a-point-sits-inside-an-arbitrary-shape)

If the shape can be converted to a bitmap another way could be to check for pixel color but this will work only if the shape edge color are different from other pixel in the shape