# Get all the coordinates inside any shape

Tags: c#, coordinates

I am creating an application and for that I have to find the coordinates any `freeshape`.
I have tried to implement that but I am not able to identify all the coordinates.

I have the coordinate value of the boundary of shape in `array`.

Like there was any shape then how can I find out all the coordinates inside this and put them in the `list<Point>`.

Comment: Are you concerned about speed? If not, just write a simple loop to check if the rasterized output has a bright pixel, and append to a list.

Comment: I don't understand can you please explain a bit

Comment: You want to get all the pixels inside the shape?

Comment: Yes but the shape can be anything.

Comment: Is this for image rendering purposes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486499/determine-if-a-point-sits-inside-an-arbitrary-shape. unless you are asking about the ray casting itself.

Comment: yes it is for image processing after getting the coordinates I have to find the pixel value of image on that coordinates.

Comment: I still dont get it, why do you need _all_ the pixels? What is the end goal?

Comment: What do the pixels have to do with temperature?

Comment: If you were using any other language, I'd simply multiply your thermal conductivity map with this image. In the long term, you might consider using a [library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336701/recommendation-for-c-sharp-matrix-library) or language with better numerical support (C++, Python, ...).

Comment: What's the nature of the `Point` structure you;re working with? Is it using integers or floats to represent coordinates? If the latter, realise that there isn't usually "a" set of points in a given area - you need to decide what granularity of points you want to work with, and almost always it's not the lowest representable for your range of values.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: From what I understand, you want to multiply the interior of your shape by a thermal conductivity map that corresponds with each pixel.

I'd recommend:

- Floodfill the interior of your shape. (See image processing libraries such as AForge.NET.)
- Perform an element-wise multiplication it with your thermal conductivity map. (See numerical libraries.)

The result is a heatmap of "temperature". You can process it further as desired.

---

<s>If you're not concerned about speed, take the rasterized output and simply check for the presence of a bright pixel:</s>

```
var img = /* some 2D array */;
var list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

foreach ((var row, var j) in img.Select((x, i) => Tuple.Create(x, i))) {
    foreach ((var pixel, var i) in row.Select((x, i) => Tuple.Create(x, i))) {
        if (pixel == 255) {
            list.Add(Tuple.Create(i, j));
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps a LINQ version:

```
img
    .Select((r, j) => new {row = r, j = j})
    .Select((t, j) => t.row
        .Select((p, i) => new {p = p, i = i, j = j})
        .Where(t => t.p == 255)
        .Select(t => Tuple.Create(t.i, t.j)))
    .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: And what happen for the pixel inside the shape

Comment: I'm confused: do you want a list of the *boundary pixels*... or *pixels within the boundary*?

Comment: I want the pixel within the boundary

Comment: OK, I think I finally see where this is going. Instead of looking for a list of all the pixels, I would recommend the following approach in the edit above.

Comment: Thank you sir for the valuable recommendation but as of now I need the pixel coordinates inside the shape