# How to know if a point is outside a set of points in an image?

Tags: python, algorithm, image, geometry

[image]

If we take any point from this image, how can we tell if that point is inside these set of points, when we have the positions of all these points?

Comment: Please see [determine if a point sits inside an arbitrary shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486499/determine-if-a-point-sits-inside-an-arbitrary-shape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shapely`:

Sample code below:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon

point = Point(0.5, 0.5)
polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
print(polygon.contains(point))
```

Comment: It doesn't works as the library expects the positions to be like in a graph, i.e, (0, 0) in the bottom left... But in an image, (0, 0) is in the top right

Comment: @NITINAGARWAL this change in coordinates is akin to looking at the polygon and the point of interest through a mirror. If the point is inside the polygon in the original image, then it will be inside the polygon in the mirror, and vice versa. Hence it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Stef Then the reason must be something else as why that code is not working... I tried it but its not working

Comment: @NITINAGARWAL what does "it's not working" mean? Is there an error message? What is the error message? Is it returning the wrong result? What data did you test it on and what result did you expect?

Comment: @Stef Oops! Previously it gave the wrong result... But it was an implementation issue.. After fixing it, the code works properly.... Thanks!